# Magento 2.0 - Multiple Simple Products redirecting to the same Configurable product in different Categories

Tags: magento2, category, configurable-product, redirect, simple-product

I am not sure the best and cleanest way to do this, preferable from the admin panel.  However, I sell different sports products with different teams.  Right now, each team has it's own product page.  There are a couple of problems with this though.  First, I believe this can cause some duplicate product issues with SEO/PPC, because they are all very similar titles and descriptions, the only thing really changing is the team name.  Second, it makes it harder for the customer to go find the same product for a different team, so I think it affects the customer experience.

My thought is to have it so customers can still go to the subcategory with the team they are mainly shopping for, click on that, see a list of products for that team with those team pictures and then click on it and it would go to the main configurable product page, preferable with that option picked.  I realize this may be a lot to ask, so I am open.

Right now in my demo store I setup, I can have the configurable broader product in the main category for example and then have the simple team product in a sub category.  The problem is that the simple product doesn't redirect to the configurable product, so it doesn't really help me with my duplicate content issues.

Any thoughts on this? I have seen clothing stores do it for different colors, because customers may not click it unless it is the color they were looking for.  A 301 redirect from the simple product may work, but I am not sure that is really the best way to go about it especially for SEO purposes.